# Cannot read property 'ObjectTracker' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm still new to Angular development, I'm trying to use https://trackingjs.com/ in my typescript angular app, I have included the type definitions but getting the

> MonitorComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'ObjectTracker' of undefined

my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { tracking } from 'tracking';

@Component({
 selector: 'monitor',
 templateUrl: './monitor.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./monitor.component.css']
})
export class MonitorComponent implements OnInit {


constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker(['face']);

    tracking.track('#video', tracker);

    tracker.on('track', function (event) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        event.data.forEach(function (rect) {
            context.strokeStyle = '#a64ceb';
            context.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
            context.font = '11px Helvetica';
            context.fillStyle = "#fff";
            context.fillText('x: ' + rect.x + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 11);
            context.fillText('y: ' + rect.y + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 22);
        });
    });
}



}   });
    }
```

HTML

```
   <div class="demo-frame">
                    <div class="demo-container">
                        <video id="video" width="320" height="240" preload autoplay loop muted></video>
                        <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

typedefinition edit

```
 declare namespace tracking {
  export class ColorTracker extends Tracker {
    constructor(colours: string[]);

    static registerColor(name: string, predicate: (r: number, g: number, b:         
    number) => boolean): void;
  }

  export class ObjectTracker extends Tracker {
    constructor(objects: string[]);
  }

  class Tracker {
    constructor(target: string);
    on(eventName: string, callback: (event: TrackEvent) => void): void;
  }

  interface TrackEvent {
    data: TrackRect[];
  }

   interface TrackRect {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    height: number;
    width: number;
    color: string;
  }

  interface TrackerTask {
    stop(): void;
    run(): void;
  }

  export function track(selector: string, tracker: tracking.Tracker): 
TrackerTask;
}
```

Any assistance and code improvements would be appreciated.

Comment: i am using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/tracking but think im using it wrong because it doesnt have a module?

Comment: @Und3rTow i changed the declare namescpace in typedef to export module , think this is wrong and not sure how to use it correct

Comment: Haven't used this particular lib before, but I see there is a open issue somewhat related to this - https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js/issues/177

Comment: try `import 'tracking'; const o = new tracking.ObjectTracker()`

Comment: @unional same result

Comment: @unional Done it with this now 
        const o = new tracking.ObjectTracker([]);

Doesnt throw error but shows nothing

Comment: Then it has the problem as mentioned by @Und3rTow. I would look in DefinitelyTyped and create an issue on using that typings (@types/tracking). /cc people who edit that file.

Comment: If it does not throw error, that it should be fine. It is no longer TS issue.

Comment: Check usage of the library. (by the way, you can easily double check if you are accessing the code correctly by `console.log(tracking)` or `console.log(tracking.ObjectTracker)`

Comment: @Und3rTow thanks for the assistance got it to work

Comment: @unional  thanks for the assistance got it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the library does not provide a format that can be consumed by NodeJS (see https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js/issues/177 mentioned by @Und3rTow)

You cannot use import statements that import a variable for it.

Alternatively, you can use `import 'tracking'` to tell TypeScript to import the package, which it will declare the `tracking` variable at the global namespace.

It is the same as doing `require('tracking')` in NodeJS with JavaScript.

After that, you can use the `tracking` variable as is.